# Understanding the Proof for why Jeffreys' prior is invariant

Tags: bayesian, uninformative-prior, jeffreys-prior

I was reviewing the section of Andrew Gelman's "Bayesian Data Analysis" on uninformative priors, and came across this explanation for why Jeffreys' prior is invariant to parameterization.

[image: Bayesian Data Analysis, 3e p. 53]

My question is simply how Gelman reasoned from the first line of the equation to the second.

---

EDIT:

So using the chain rule, is this the correct reasoning?
If we take $\theta(\phi)$ as a function of $\phi$, then

$$
\frac{d^2\log p(y \mid \phi)}{d\phi^2} 
= \frac{d}{d\phi} \left( \frac{d \log p(y\mid\theta(\phi))}{d \theta} \frac{d\theta}{d\phi} \right)
= \frac{d^2 \log p(y\mid\theta(\phi))}{d \theta^2} \left|\frac{d\theta}{d\phi} \right|^2
$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: I agree with William Huber. It simply amounts to the chain rule of calculus.

Comment: Thanks both, I got myself confused because it was to the right of the conditional. Added an updated explanation in an edit.

Comment: This explanation is of course restricted to the unidimensional case.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your edit, that's not right. You also need the product rule:

\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2\log p(y | \phi)}{d\phi^2} 
&= \frac{d}{d\phi} \left( \frac{d \log p(y|\theta(\phi))}{d \theta} \frac{d\theta}{d\phi} \right) \tag{chain rule}\\
&= \left(\frac{d^2 \log p(y|\theta(\phi))}{d \theta d\phi}\right)\left( \frac{d\theta}{d\phi}\right) + \left(\frac{d \log p(y|\theta(\phi))}{d \theta}\right) \left( \frac{d^2\theta}{d\phi^2}\right) \tag{prod. rule} \\
&= \left(\frac{d^2 \log p(y|\theta(\phi))}{d \theta^2 }\right)\left( \frac{d\theta}{d\phi}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{d \log p(y|\theta(\phi))}{d \theta}\right) \left( \frac{d^2\theta}{d\phi^2}\right) \tag{chain rule}
\end{align*}
Then $\frac{d \log p(y|\theta(\phi))}{d \theta}$ (the "score function") is $0$ on average.